# Why the oddity of speculative/non-specified large numbers

Tags: etymology, numbers

When there is a large number to describe, without knowing the specific number, we can report "millions," or "thousands," or "hundreds." Why do we then break that base-ten (seeming) pattern with "dozens," rather than simply "tens"?

Comment: Because dozens (scores?) of generations of English speakers weren't that fully committed to the metric system originally.

Comment: Although it doesn't seem that grosses of them were :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: a fair point, but then where are the similarly-based larger numbers? Or did observers not need* to discuss quantities above the high hundreds (which would be served by grosses, as Matt implies)? (I realise that 'need' is somewhat subjective, but I couldn't think of a better word for that question.)

Comment: French speakers use douzaine (twelve, around a dozen)/ dizaine (ten, around ten). And let's not forget the scores of English speakers that use *score* for 20. I thought that a search for "tens of protestors" would be fruitless, but several popped up immediately. One was from a Turkish news service and the other from a Bulgarian news service, both translated into English.

Comment: @DavidThomas - no, they didn't use large numbers but changed units. That's why it is 10 score rather than 200. If you look at Roman and Greek numerals the numbers topped out in the thousands.

Comment: @rajah9: I'm assuming that the English-language word "dozen" is derived from "douzaine" then? That's a beautiful word.

Comment: Yes, *dozen* comes from *douzaine.* From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dozen: "The English word dozen comes from the old form douzaine, a French word meaning 'a group of twelve'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, we have perhaps a score of special words used to describe certain Imperial numbers.  Most of these come from historically important units of measure.  There's at least a couple words that mean **2**. A common reason is the symmetry of the human body, and the need to describe our pair of legs, among other matched body parts.

Of course, we can't forget about commerce.  Approximately a half-dozen words come to us because those numbers showed up regularly, especially in British Commerce.  For example, we used to have twelve pennies to a shilling, and twenty shillings to a pound.

Also, it was common for goods to be ordered in quantities of twelve.  Twelve is easily dividable by 2, 3, and 4, so it was easier to break things up.  However, bakers didn't want to be caught shorting their customers, so they threw an extra loaf into an order of 12.

While there's at least a gross of words that describe all the power-of-ten numbers, I think it's a shame that we don't have more Imperial number words.  Powers of twelve do have a lot going for them; they're just very obnoxious in a base-10 system.

If we put our heads together, we might even be able to come up with great gross of words, and show those new fangled mathematicians a thing or two about using language to talk about numbers.

http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/numbers/words/intro.htm